# Question in error in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i have a question if you please help me i have an error

> Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@Deitails".

and i can not find out whats the problem since i am not aware what Scalar is about

```
 var sqlCon = new
 SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

             // GET CONFERENCE ROLE ID


             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
             cmd.Connection = sqlCon;
             cmd.CommandText = "select Conference_Role_ID from AuthorPaper
 where Paper_ID = @PaperId";
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaperId",
 paperId);
             cmd.Connection.Open();
             string ConferenceRoleId = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
             cmd.Connection.Close();
             cmd.Dispose();




                 string query2 = @"insert into
 ReviewPaper(Overall_Rating,Paper_id,Conference_role_id,Deitails)

                              values(0,@paperId,@ConferenceRoleId,@Deitails);select
 SCOPE_IDENTITY() as RPID";

                 cmd = new SqlCommand(query2, sqlCon);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paperId",
 paperId);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConferenceRoleId",
 ConferenceRoleId);

             string ReviewPaperId;

                 try
                 {
                     cmd.Connection.Open();
                     ReviewPaperId = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                     cmd.Connection.Close();
                 }
                 catch (Exception ee) { throw ee; }
                 finally { cmd.Dispose(); }
```

thanks

Comment: You need to give more information. Please post some code.

Comment: Could just be that you mispelled Details.

Comment: I voted to reopen, since the error is a very specific one and easy to answer. The OP has clearly no clue where to start, And closing a question in <2mins is a bit too rude, give the OP some time to keep him motivated.

Comment: You need one of these: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue for @Details

Comment: @PHeiberg why would you ask for more information **AND** vote to close a question, so that OP could not possibly provide more information? OP is obviously a beginner and new comer to SO, are you trying to drive people away? Besides, it really isn't difficult to know what is going on here. "Scalar" is a term only used in one context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a line of code which says

```
string query2 = @"insert into ReviewPaper(Overall_Rating, Paper_id, 
    Conference_role_id, Deitails) values (0,@paperId,@ConferenceRoleId,@Deitails); 
    select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as RPID";
```

You provide the parameters `@paperId`, `@ConferenceRoleId` and `@Deitails` for the values for the insert statement.  Later you specify the value for the first two parameters, but not `@Deitails`:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paperId", paperId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConferenceRoleId", ConferenceRoleId);
```

You need to add a similar line to add the value for `@Deitails` so that SQL server knows what to do with it.  The error you are getting is coming from SQL server because by not adding a value for `@Deitails` in your C# code, it is not being declared for you in the SQL code which is sent to the server.

To answer your other question, 'Scalar' in this case means that the variable `@Deitails` represents a single value.

Answer (score 7):

You have a SQL query with a parameter named `Details`, but you forgot to add the parameter.